# R: converting alphabet grade into factor

Tags: r

so i have a group of data with grades from A+ to F (and 99 dunno why that's there)

what I'm trying to do is convert A+~B0 into "high" and C+ ~ F into "low"

i have a column of "result" which has the list of alphabet data.

i'm creating another column "grade" into the factor "high" "low"

```
raw.tidy$grade <- raw.tidy$result(high = c("A+", "A0", "B+", "B0"),
                                  low = c("C+", "C0", "D+", "D0", "F", "99"))
```

this is the code i'm using but this gives 
Error: attempt to apply non-function
error.

i've checked up other questions and i can convert A+ into A+ and C0 into C0 but i can't understand how to conver A+ and A0 into "high".

Comment: Some software systems use `99` as a missing value. You may want to map `99` to `NA` rather than to `"low"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `case_when()` function from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  result = c("A+", "B0", "D+", "F", "A0", "99", "C+", "A+", "C0", "D0")
)

df %>% 
  mutate(grade = factor(case_when(
    result %in% c("A+", "A0", "B+", "B0") ~ "high",
    result %in% c("C+", "C0", "D+", "D0", "F", "99") ~ "low"
  )))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   result grade
   <chr>  <fct>
 1 A+     high 
 2 B0     high 
 3 D+     low  
 4 F      low  
 5 A0     high 
 6 99     low  
 7 C+     low  
 8 A+     high 
 9 C0     low  
10 D0     low
```

For more on `case_when`, refer to the [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) on the tidyverse.org website.

Comment: oh wow. that really does the magic. i really should look up the %in% and %>%.
BIG THANKS!

Comment: @Sunwoong ENFYS Cho If my answer satisfied your question, please check it to accept the answer. This helps others who may find this post as well as gives me points so I can win the game of SO (haha).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findInterval` function:

```
vec = c("D+", "A0", "F", "D0", "99", "B0", "B+", "C+", "C0", "A+")

c("High","Low")[findInterval(vec>"C"|vec=="99",0:1)]

[1] "Low"  "High" "Low"  "Low"  "Low"  "High" "High" "Low"  "Low"  "High"
```

or even

```
factor(findInterval(vec>"C" | vec == "99", 0:1 ), label = c("High","Low"))

[1] Low  High Low  Low  Low  High High Low  Low  High
Levels: High Low
```

if you have a dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(result=vec,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

transform(df,grade=factor(findInterval(result>"C"|result=="99",0:1),label=c("High","Low")))
   result grade
1      D+   Low
2      A0  High
3       F   Low
4      D0   Low
5      99   Low
6      B0  High
7      B+  High
8      C+   Low
9      C0   Low
10     A+  High
```

Yu can see the [Demo here](http://rextester.com/live/KUKXG4194)

Comment: Did not know about the function (+1). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With base R

```
high = c("A+", "A0", "B+", "B0")

low = c("C+", "C0", "D+", "D0", "F", "99")


df$grade <- factor(ifelse(df$result %in% high, "high","low"))
```